# ExtJS 6, collapsed and expanded tree - drag and drop problems

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jih

Here is the link to a fiddle. Problem is that after tree is collapsed and then expanded, drag and drop stop working. I'm using Ext.dd.DragZone.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Try to drag Child 1, for example. You will see that it works.
2. Collapse and expand Root
3. You will see that Child 1 (and all other childs) become not draggable

Comment: Your fiddler is not working. Can you please check

Comment: Check once again, please

Answer (score 1):

You are only adding the drag zones to tree nodes on startup. When nodes are collapsed and expanded again, their child nodes are destroyed and recreated. You should be able to add the drag zone again to all child nodes in the [`expand`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.NodeInterface.html#event-expand) event:

```
_addDDDragToNode = function (node) {
    var me = this;

    var treeView = node.getOwnerTree().getView();
    me._addDDDragZone(treeView.getNode(node));
    node.on('expand',_addDDDragToNode, me);

    Ext.each(node.childNodes, function(el){
        me._addDDDragToNode(el);
    });
};
```

That this solution doesn't work seems to be a Sencha bug: A subcomponent (status proxy) of the dragzone is not destroyed when the dragzone is destroyed. I'm not completely sure how to circumvent that bug.

Comment: yes, I tried to recreate it on expand, too, and got proxy error. Error told that element with the same id already exist or something like this. So, possibly, some alternative solution can be found...

Comment: Can you please go to Sencha forum and also ask there about the bug, so they know there's something fishy?